# Generate XML output from a variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using below XSLT code to get XML data into a variable

```
 <xsl:variable name="vOWGCustom" select="document('mctx:vars/v_OWG_Custom')"/>
 <xsl:variable name="v.OWG_Custom" select="$vOWGCustom/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry [wd:emplid = $v.emplid]"/>
```

When I try to check this value it gives me data is text format and not XML.

```
 <report_data><xsl:value-of select="$v.OWG_Custom"/></report_data>
```

How can I generate the data in XML format.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I generate the data in XML format.

```
<report_data><xsl:copy-of select="$v.OWG_Custom"/></report_data>
```

Comment: I had earlier tried using <xsl:copy-of select="$v.OWG_Custom"></xsl:copy-of> but it did not work. Was it because <report_data> tags were missing ?

Comment: @Pravin I don't know. You have showed no input XML, no complete XSLT code, no desired output XML. How would I know what "it did not work" means for you?